# NullPointerException in Loop

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I've created a program that attempts to crack password protected zip files using a dictionary. The program reads from a line, stores that line in an ArrayList at position 0, then tries to open the locked zip file with it. If it is successful, it closes the buffered reader and announces the working password. If it is not successful, it ignores the produced ZipException, clears the password from position 0 in the ArrayList, and continues with the next line. I've included debugging to show the number of items in the ArrayList after each attempt (should always be 1).

Code Snippet (Error):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile.setPassword(ZipFile.java:650)
    at zZipCracker.zZipCracker.zZipCracker(zZipCracker.java:87)
    at zZipCracker.zZipCracker.main(zZipCracker.java:55)
```

Code Snippet (My Loop):

```
while(true) { //while elements are still in the array list
                    String line;
                    if ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                       passwordArray.add(line);
                       System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    zipper.setPassword((String) passwordArray.get(0)); //set the password to element position [passwordCounter]
                    System.out.println("Testing password no." + passwordCounter + ", which is " + passwordArray.get(0));
                    passwordCounter = passwordCounter + 1;

                    try {
                         zipper.extractAll(dest);
                         br.close();
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The zip has been cracked. The password is " + passwordArray.get(0));
                         break;
                    } catch(ZipException ze) {
                        System.out.println(passwordArray.size());
                        passwordArray.remove(0);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
        } else {
                zipper.extractAll(dest);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The selected zip was not password protected. It was extracted anyways.");
        }
```

Code Snippet (Just line 87):

```
zipper.setPassword((String) passwordArray.get(0));
```

Code Snippet (Output before the exception):

```
darkside
Testing password no.4747, which is darkside
1
angie1
Testing password no.4748, which is angie1
1
321456
Testing password no.4749, which is 321456
1

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Why are you calling `passwordArray.get(0)` and why are you casting to `String`?

Comment: for that matter, why are you testing on `(line = br.readLine()) != null`, acknowledging that it can become `null`, but then not have all the code that should trigger on not null inside that conditional?

Comment: It was a damn blank line in the dictionary... http://pastebin.com/UMRBPTnB

Answer (score 0):

Make this condition to the whole while loop, When the line is null, it wont add with the passwordArray. But the next line you are trying to get the value from the passwordArray.get(0).  So you have to make the condition for the whole code.

```
   while (true)
    { //while elements are still in the array list
        String line;
        if ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            passwordArray.add(line);
            System.out.println(line);

            zipper.setPassword((String) passwordArray.get(0)); //set the password to element position [passwordCounter]
            System.out.println("Testing password no." + passwordCounter + ", which is " + passwordArray.get(0));
            passwordCounter = passwordCounter + 1;

            try
            {
                zipper.extractAll(dest);
                br.close();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The zip has been cracked. The password is " + passwordArray.get(0));
                break;
            }
            catch (ZipException ze)
            {
                System.out.println(passwordArray.size());
                passwordArray.remove(0);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the dictionary first...

```
gorillaz
foxylady
darkside
angie1
321456

summer05
sabrina1
rosalinda
roderick
muslim
matilde
indigo
```

"So simple it hurts."